# undefined method: connect_timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Browser error:

```
NoMethodError
undefined method `connect_timeout=' for #<Mysql2::Client:0x47f7570>
```

On my browser, an error comes up that connect_timeout is undefined. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the client.rb file. I'll show you the file. I had to edit some of it to actually get Webrick up and running. When I started the server, an error always appeared on my command line unless I made the changes. I've commented on what I have edited. Sometimes edited random things and some of them worked but they produced different errors on my browser. I am using a windows 8 machine. Thank you for helping.

```
module Mysql2
class Client
attr_reader :query_options, :read_timeout
@@default_query_options = {
  :as => :hash,                   # the type of object you want each row back as; also supports :array (an array of values)
  :async => false,                # don't wait for a result after sending the query, you'll have to monitor the socket yourself then eventually call Mysql2::Client#async_result
  :cast_booleans => false,        # cast tinyint(1) fields as true/false in ruby
  :symbolize_keys => false,       # return field names as symbols instead of strings
  :database_timezone => :local,   # timezone Mysql2 will assume datetime objects are stored in
  :application_timezone => nil,   # timezone Mysql2 will convert to before handing the object back to the caller
  :cache_rows => true,            # tells Mysql2 to use it's internal row cache for results
  #:connect_flags => REMEMBER_OPTIONS | LONG_PASSWORD | LONG_FLAG | TRANSACTIONS | PROTOCOL_41 | SECURE_CONNECTION,
  #I had to delete the line above because for some reason the command prompt said that each of the constants were undefined were not used in the right place or something
  :cast => true,
  :default_file => nil,
  :default_group => nil
}

def initialize (opts = {})
  opts = Mysql2::Util.key_hash_as_symbols( opts )
  @read_timeout = nil
  @query_options = @@default_query_options.dup
  @query_options.merge! opts

  #initialize_ext
  # the chrome page said that the above variable is undefined :P

  # Set default connect_timeout to avoid unlimited retries from signal interruption
  opts[:connect_timeout] = 120 unless opts.key?(:connect_timeout)

  [:reconnect, :connect_timeout, :local_infile, :read_timeout, :write_timeout, :default_file, :default_group, :secure_auth, :init_command].each do |key|
    next unless opts.key?(key)
    case key
    when :reconnect, :local_infile, :secure_auth
      send(:"#{key}=", !!opts[key])
    when :connect_timeout, :read_timeout, :write_timeout
      send(:"#{key}=", opts[key].to_i)
    else
      send(:"#{key}=", opts[key])
    end
  end

  # force the encoding to utf8
  self.charset_name = opts[:encoding] || 'utf8'

  ssl_options = opts.values_at(:sslkey, :sslcert, :sslca, :sslcapath, :sslcipher)
  ssl_set(*ssl_options) if ssl_options.any?

  if [:user,:pass,:hostname,:dbname,:db,:sock].any?{|k| @query_options.has_key?(k) }
    warn "============= WARNING FROM mysql2 ============="
    warn "The options :user, :pass, :hostname, :dbname, :db, and :sock will be deprecated at some point in the future."
    warn "Instead, please use :username, :password, :host, :port, :database, :socket, :flags for the options."
    warn "============= END WARNING FROM mysql2 ========="
  end

  user     = opts[:username] || opts[:user]
  pass     = opts[:password] || opts[:pass]
  host     = opts[:host] || opts[:hostname]
  port     = opts[:port]
  database = opts[:database] || opts[:dbname] || opts[:db]
  socket   = opts[:socket] || opts[:sock]
  flags    = opts[:flags] ? opts[:flags] | @query_options[:connect_flags] : @query_options[:connect_flags]

  # Correct the data types before passing these values down to the C level
  user = user.to_s unless user.nil?
  pass = pass.to_s unless pass.nil?
  host = host.to_s unless host.nil?
  port = port.to_i unless port.nil?
  database = database.to_s unless database.nil?
  socket = socket.to_s unless socket.nil?

  connect user, pass, host, port, database, socket, flags
end

def self.default_query_options
  @@default_query_options
end

def query_info
  info = query_info_string
  return {} unless info
  info_hash = {}
  info.split.each_slice(2) { |s| info_hash[s[0].downcase.delete(':').to_sym] = s[1].to_i }
  info_hash
end

private
  def self.local_offset
    ::Time.local(2010).utc_offset.to_r / 86400
  end

end
end
```

Comment: Could you please briefly explain why you're doing that at all?

Answer (score 0):

`Mysql2::Client#initialize` called `connect_timeout=` but there isn't such attr_writer in the client.

```
when :connect_timeout, :read_timeout, :write_timeout
  send(:"#{key}=", opts[key].to_i)
else
```

If this client is written by yourself, add `attr_accessor :connect_timeout` in `Mysql2::Client`'s definition and make proper use of the attribute. If it is from other library, check your load path. You may have missed some files that opened `Mysql2::Client` and monkey patched it.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm very sorry but I'm quite new to computer programming. Could you please explain what each term means from your answer? I'm not sure exactly how mysql works with this stuff . So what are the attr_writers in the client? And do I copy-paste the code you gave below that because I can't seem to find that in client.rb. Also, I think ruby on rails generated this page for me but the command line kept making me change it to start up the web server. Also, I just searched client.rb on my computer and that's how I found it. Thank you for helping.